How do I add lore to an item using in-game commands and/or Universal Minecraft Editor?
A friend and I are making a map that requires lore on items. How would we do that?
How do we add lore to an item using in-game commands and/or Universal Minecraft Editor?

Please see our guide on asking Minecraft commands questions, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far.” Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

@galacticninja There doesn't seem to be much info on lore in BE, to give the benefit of the doubt

I don't understand the question, how are you supposed to add "lore" to an item? What exactly do you mean?

@pinckerman "Lore" on a Minecraft item is custom description and display names. Java is very well documented, for example using this generator, but Bedrock doesn't seem to have anything for it... You can create a custom item with a default name/description/icon/etc., but you can't make it per-item.

@aytimothy that makes sense, thank you

Unfortunately, you cannot add lore to an item or give yourself an item with lore using commands in Bedrock Edition.
Using Universal Minecraft Editor

Make sure the item is in a container or in your inventory so you can edit its entries. A slot with an item has more entries than a blank slot.
Once you have located your item, make a compound in the item's entries compound and name it tag.
In the tag compound, make a compound named display.
In the display compound, make a list named Lore.
In Lore, make a new text. In this text, you can put the lore you want the item to have. Once done typing, make sure to hit enter to save the text, or else it will disappear.
Save your edits using the save button on the top left.

Notes:

You can use § formatting to change the color or formatting of the text. For example, in the text inside Lore, you can use something like §eThe only weapon that can slay the dragon. to make it show in blue in-game.
To have multiple lines of lore, add an additional text in Lore after the preceding text and type in the text you want to show in the other line.

Source: 


